# How connect to IBM MQ using Jms

Tags: java, ibm-mq

Please help me.
I can't send a normal hello world to the queue. Because it gives an authorization error. The fact is that the connection to the queue manager is carried out through the user, a password is not needed for it. I can't figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong.

```
import javax.jms.*;
import javax.jms.Message;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.*;
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsFactoryFactoryImpl;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;
import org.apache.camel.Producer;

public class SenderMQ {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String QMName = "";
        String requstQueueName = "";

        try {
            JmsFactoryFactory jff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
            JmsConnectionFactory jcf = jff.createConnectionFactory();

            jcf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, host);
            jcf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, 1414);
            jcf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL,"SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN");
            jcf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE,WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            jcf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER,"N_QM");
            jcf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, String.valueOf(true));
            jcf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, "admin");
            jcf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, null);

            Connection connection = jcf.createConnection();
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            Destination destination = session.createQueue("queue://EGG_TEST_IN");
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);

            long uniqueNUmber = System.currentTimeMillis()%1000;
            String mess_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF8\"?><RequestMessage xmlns=\"MQMessage\" processID=\"FD12C7B4617F11ecB2E0005056AD53F8\" serviceID=\"SMEV3_ESIA3_IM\" departmentID=\"0\" systemID=\"SBL_FR:ULBSFCNT\"><Request>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</Request></RequestMessage>";
            TextMessage messag = session.createTextMessage(mess_xml);
            connection.start();

            producer.send(messag);

        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What to do with such a output:

> ```
> com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: The
> security authentication was not valid that was supplied for
> QueueManager 'N_MQ' with connection mode 'Client' and host name
> 'localhost(1414)'. Please check if the supplied username and password
> are correct on the QueueManager to which you are connecting.
>                 at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:531)
>                 at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215)
>                 at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:424)
>                 at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8475)
>                 at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:7815)
>                 at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl._createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:303)
>                 at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:236)
>                 at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6016)
>                 at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6041)
>                 at SenderMQ.main(SenderMQ.java:28)
>                 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)
>                 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
>                 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>                 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
>                 at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
> Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with
> compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
>                 at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
>                 ... 13 more
> ```

Comment: You will need to look in the queue manager error logs to find the exact cause.   Note that if you are just trying to send that username with no password you should set the MQCSP setting to false.

Comment: @JoshMc, Thanks, now I got a more intelligible error) I will understand further

Comment: @Sheva12 do not use SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN channel.  Have your MQAdmin create a channel for your application to use.

Comment: Please update with the new error and if you found a solution as a self answer.

Comment: @JoshMc, There are no errors, the program fulfills, but does not queue

Comment: You started "Thanks, now I got a more intelligible error"

Comment: @Sheva12 Can you please post the answer in comment if the issue is fixed and what changes you made to fix it . And do accept your answer That would help some one also facing the same kind of issue.